# Objective-C Bug this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dateAMPM

Tags: ios, objective-c, undefined, nsunknownkeyexception

While I was working on my IPhone application for school I was in the midst of storing the data so it could be used after closing the application and I changed the name of one of the variables from dateAMPM to alarmAMPM and now it is giving me this error:
2014-10-23 19:33:12.093 Exercise Alarm[24489:811187] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dateAMPM.'

Comment: Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSUnknownKeyException+this+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant+for+the+key) before posting. This has been covered many many times.

Comment: Well, you forgot to change the name in a variable access to `dateAMPM`. You renamed the variable and did not rename all accesses of it. The error message specifically indicates the old name. Everything is there to find the problem, go a global search in the project for `dateAMPM`.

Comment: You need to put [the smallest amount of relevant code that displays the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into your question here; a link to your entire project does not make an acceptable Stack Overflow post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the storyboard.

You still have the dateAMPM and the dateLabel outlets tied to the initial view controller. you actually have to right click on the first icon on the top and manually delete the connection (click on the cross), where the yellow warning sign displays.

[image: screenshot].